# ExecuteExcel4Macro to return cell formating information?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to use ExecuteExcel4Macro to return cell formatting?  I use the code below to get values from closed workbooks, is it possible to also return data about the cell itself?

```
Private Sub Silent_Extraction()

    Path_ = "SomePath"
    File_ = "SomeFile.xlsm"
    Sheet_ = "SomeSheet"
    Rng_ = Range("A1").Address(1, 1, xlR1C1)
    Send_String = "'" & Path_ & "[" & File_ & "]" & Sheet_ & "'!" & Rng_

    Returned = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Send_String)

End Sub
```

I tried putting a public function such as isBold into the executeexcel4macro argument, but didn't get anywhere.

Also, where can I see a list of ALL available parameters for the ExecuteExcel4Macro, I've seen things like GET."something" but have no reference to the other options.

Comment: This is an off-site link with the list of arguments on [MrExcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20611-info-only-get-cell-arguments.html).  Excel 4 came with written reference material, including a Function Reference which included all of the arguments and all of the functions. MS also still has a `HELP` file, but it is of an older type, and the reader is not included in Windows 10 / Office 365

Comment: The short answer is no. `GET.CELL` doesn't work on closed workbooks.